# google map loading issue using javascript createElement

Tags: google-maps

I am developing a widget to show some data from my site to others. For that I have to load some script files dynamically via javascript createElement method. Here is my code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
//initMap();
};
script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
function initMap()
{
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 12,
 center: myLatlng,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

};
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Hello World!"
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
initMap();
});
</script>
```

This code initialize map neither in script.onload function and not on document.ready. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, but it seems google maps api is not loaded completely when dynamically loaded.
Instead you can use Google Loader
https://developers.google.com/loader/
which does fine.

Here is your modified `<script>`:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://raw.github.com/getify/LABjs/master/LAB.min.js";
script.onload = function() {
    $LAB
        .script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js')
        // .script('...') // other scripts which DO NOT depend on maps API

        // if script X depends on jquery for example, it must be loaded like this:
        // .wait() // this makes sure scripts above (jquery) are loaded before continuing
        // .script('X')
        .script('https://www.google.com/jsapi')
        .wait(function() {
            // this is called after everything above is loaded
            google.load("maps", "3", 
                {
                    "callback" : onMapsLoad, // called when maps api loaded
                    "other_params": "sensor=false"
                });
        });
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

function onMapsLoad() {
    $LAB
        // add here scripts which DEPEND on Maps API
        .script('https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js')
        .wait(
            function() {
                // called when all above is loaded
                $(function() { // makes sure DOM is ready
                    initMap();
                });
            }
        );
}

function initMap()
{
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 12,
 center: myLatlng,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}; var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Hello World!"
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working fine now. But I have to call map functions when jquery, google map, infobox and fancybox have been loaded and I am stuck into it. I am sorry if I am asking any irrelevant question. but its being hard for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use http://labjs.com/ for script loading. Instead of creating script tag with `jsapi`,put https://raw.github.com/getify/LABjs/master/LAB.min.js and then in the `onload` handler execute something like:  
`$LAB  
.script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js')  
/* .script('...') other needed scripts  */
.script('https://www.google.com/jsapi')  
.wait(function() {  
...  
});`  
Whatever you put in the `wait()` callback will be executed after all scripts are loaded. You should put `google.load` there also.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working fine when i load local scripts but it does not load google maps api and infobox.js correctly :(.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include separate script loading before and after maps api is loaded.

Comment: Thanks alot @cleric. You helped me alot to achieve my goal. My widget is working alright now.